# Laravel running in an Ubuntu VPS

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Laravel I recently put it in a VPS I could download, I could use composer, BUT I do not know what it's happening because I go into the folder with URL I mean, I write:

http://myproject.com/

It should be shown me something but it is not happening, when i do that it just makes a download and it does not display anything.

You can test it http://dominicanspasalon.com/  then make click in dominican_spa_salon where the larave is... you will see that it does not display anything, it just makes the download... what could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Your server is misconfigured. The webserver's document root should be configured to point at the `public` folder, and you don't appear to have configured your server to serve PHP files.

Comment: If a PHP file is being downloaded it means NGINX or Apache is not using `fpm module `or the `php cgi` to look at php. It thinks it's a downloadable file. Look at your web server setup. What web server are you using?

Comment: It could be anything hire a professional, or use service like https://forge.laravel.com or ask specific question on the right SE. If you are going to do this alone I recommend you watch https://serversforhackers.com/series. Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

If nginx you need edit Nginx Configuration "server {}". In that file change **root** path.

Good luck!

Comment: That's a start, but it's not running PHP at all; that's not going to be fixed by changing the document root.